# Force Jackson to add addional wrapping using annotations

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following class:

```
public class Message {
    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }    
}
```

When converting the instance to JSON using Jackson by default I get:

```
{"text":"Text"}
```

I would like to get:

```
{"message":{"text":"Text"}}
```

**Is there any JAXB / Jackson annotation I can use to achieve my goal?**

As a workaround, I can wrap my class with another class:

```
public class MessageWrapper {
    private Message message;

    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

or a more generic solution:

```
public class JsonObjectWrapper<T> {
    /**
     * Using a real map to allow wrapping multiple objects
     */
    private Map<String, T> wrappedObjects = new HashMap<String, T>();

    public JsonObjectWrapper() {
    }

    public JsonObjectWrapper(String name, T wrappedObject) {
        this.wrappedObjects.put(name, wrappedObject);
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, T> any() {
        return wrappedObjects;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, T value) {
        wrappedObjects.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setText("Text");
JsonObjectWrapper<Message> wrapper = new JsonObjectWrapper<Message>("message", message);
```

**Is there any JAXB / Jackson annotation I can use to achieve my goal?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On workaround: you don't absolutely need those getters/setters, so could just have:

```
public class MessageWrapper {
  public Message message;
}
```

or perhaps add convenience constructor:

```
public class MessageWrapper {
  public Message message;
  @JsonCreator
  public MessageWrapper(@JsonProperty("message") Message m) { 
       message = m; 
  }
}
```

There is a way to add wrapping too; with 1.9 you can use `SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_ELEMENT` and `DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_ELEMENT`. And if you want to change the wrapper name (by default it is simply unqualified class name), you can use `@JsonRootName` annotation

Jackson 2.0 adds further dynamic options via `ObjectReader` and `ObjectWriter`, as well as JAX-RS annotations.

Comment: StaxMan, if the root element name of the Json String has to be ignored  during serialization, does Jackson 1.9 require us to set the `DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_ELEMENT` feature alone or the addition of the annotation `@JsonRootName` is required as well?

Comment: I'd have to verify -- UNWRAP might be enough; question is whether name has to map. But even without `@JsonRootName`, default name exists (simple class name), which may work well.

Answer (score 32):

With Jackson 2.x use can use the following to enable wrapper without adding addition properties in the ObjectMapper

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;

@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonTypeName(value = "student")
public class Student {
  private String name;
  private String id;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It was sad to learn that you must write custom serialization for the simple goal of wrapping a class with a labeled object.  After playing around with writing a custom serializer, I concluded that the simplest solution is a generic wrapper. Here's perhaps a more simple implementation of your example above:

```
public final class JsonObjectWrapper {
    private JsonObjectWrapper() {}

    public static <E> Map<String, E> withLabel(String label, E wrappedObject) {
        HashMap<String, E> map = new HashMap<String, E>();
        map.put(label, wrappedObject);
        return map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Provided you don't mind the json having a capital `m` in `message`, then the simplest way to do this is to annotate your class with [`@JsonTypeInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html).

You would add:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use=Id.NAME)
public class Message {
  // ...
}
```

to get `{"Message":{"text":"Text"}}`

Answer (score 2):

I have created a small jackson module that contains a @JsonWrapped annotation, that solves the problem. See here for the code: https://github.com/mwerlitz/jackson-wrapped

Your class would then look like:

```
public class Message {
    @JsonWrapped("message")
    private String text;
}
```

Comment: This worked really well for me! Fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

A Simpler/Better way to do it:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "message")
public class Message { ...}
```

then use
`new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true).writeValueAs...`

Answer (score 1):

If using spring, then in `application.properties` file add following:-

> spring.jackson.serialization.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true

And then use `@JsonRootName` annotation on any of your class that you wish to serialize. e.g.

```
@JsonRootName("user")
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
}
```

Comment: This will wrap _all_ JSON objects, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your object with a map

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setText("Text");

new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Map.of("message", message));
```